# Disable Unicode (force ASCII) in Outlook 2013

Tags: unicode, outlook, ascii, non-ascii-characters

Is there any way, via settings or a custom script, to force the use of ASCII-only encoding in Outlook 2013?

I often pass one-liners and code snippets between myself and other developers, and we will copy-paste them into a command-line prompt for testing various tools. A common issue is that the editor will replace hyphens `-` with some wider "full width hyphen" or "dash" character, that gets converted to an accented ASCII character when we paste it into prompts.

Right now, we resolve it by pasting it into GVIM on Windows and running a VIM script to handle the conversion, but it's a pain and can be unreliable, especially for other developers who hate using VIM. Since all correspondence is handled in English, French, or Italian anyways (we don't get picky with accents), there's no need for unicode support. Can we turn it off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and this has nothing to do with Unicode support in Outlook. This is how Outlook editor (Word) works.

EDIT: you can turn smart quotes off in Outlook: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2084-outlook-disable-turn-off-smart-quotes.html

Comment: Thanks. That's a shame. I figured if I could somehow just limit the character set, no more woes with various characters becoming mangled when pasting into `CMD`.

Comment: You should be able to turn that option off - http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/2084-outlook-disable-turn-off-smart-quotes.html

Comment: Thank you. That solves part of the problem.